# Solution of $A^\top M A=M$ for all $M$ positive-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to find all matrices $A$ such that for all positive-definite matrices $M$, $A^\top M A=M$. $I$ and $-I$ are obvious solutions. I can't find out it there are other such matrices and if so, how  to find them.

Necessarily, $A$ is invertible since $\det(A)^2\det(M)=\det(M)\neq 0$ and more precisely, $\det A=\pm 1$. But that certainly not sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that since this holds for all positive definite $M$, it holds for $M = I$. So, we must have
$$
A^TA = I
$$
which is to say that $A$ is an orthogonal (unitary) matrix.

We may therefore rewrite the equation as 
$$
A^{-1}MA = M \implies  MA = AM
$$
That is, $A$ must commute with all positive definite matrices.  However, this means that $A$ must also commute with all complex linear combinations of positive definite matrices, which is to say that $A$ must commute with *every* matrix.

It is well known that the only matrices that commute with any matrix are the multiples of the identity.

Thus, we conclude that $A$ is an orthogonal (unitary) matrix and a multiple of the identity. If $A$ is real, conclude that $A = \pm I$.  If $A$ is complex (and we take the $A^T$ to refer to the complex-conjugate), conclude that $A = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| = 1$.

Comment: nice, clean answer. I wouldn't have come up with the $M=I$ part.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, $\det(A) \neq 0$, and then $A^{-1}$ exists.
Now:

$$A^\top M A=M \Rightarrow \\(A^\top)^{-1}A^\top M AA^{-1}=(A^\top)^{-1}MA^{-1} \Rightarrow\\
M = (A^\top)^{-1}MA^{-1} \Rightarrow\\
M = (A^{-1})^\top MA^{-1}.
$$

This suggests that all matrices such that $A = A^{-1}$ and $\det(A) = \pm 1$ satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I don't see how you reached that conclusion.

Comment: And it's demostrably false: take $M = I$ and 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom good point. Then what is wrong with my calculations?

Comment: What is "wrong" is that there's no way to go from the last line of your calculations to your supposed conclusion.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. Ok, I agree with you that is wrong for sure (thanks for your example). But I don't understand why! Is $$M = (A^{-1})^\top MA^{-1}$$ correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but it doesn't suggest what you claim that it suggests.

Comment: Note that it is possible to have $$A^TMA = (A^{-1})^TMA^{-1}$$ without having $$A^TMA=M$$ In fact, the first condition is equivalent to saying that $A^2$ satisfies the requirements of $A$.